# return longest alphabetical substring

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, alphabetical

The aim of the program is to print the longest substring within variable s that is in alphabetical order.

```
s ='abchae'
currentlen = 0
longestlen = 0
current = ''
longest = ''
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for char in s:

    for number in range(0,len(s)):
    if s[number] == char:
        n = number 

    nxtchar = 1        
    alphstring = s[n] 
    while alphstring in alphabet == True and n+nxtchar <= 5:
        alphstring += s[n+nxtchar]
        nxtchar += 1
        currentlen = len(alphstring)
        current = alphstring

        if currentlen > longestlen:
            longest = current

print longest
```

When run, the program doesn't print anything. I don't seem to see what's wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the logic behind your code? SO is not a [codereview](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com) topic.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. I think I know what you mean, but as your code isn't working, maybe you're doing something else.

Comment: Should the answer be 'abc' or 'abch'?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `regex` for this

```
import re
string = 'abchae'
alphstring = re.compile(r'a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*', re.I)

longest = ''
for match in alphstring.finditer(string):
    if len(match.group()) > len(longest):
        longest = match.group()

print(longest)
```

Output:

```
abch
```

Note: The flag `re.I` in the regex expression causes the regex to ignore case.  If this is not the desired behavior you can delete the flag and it will only match lowercase characters.

Comment: I never would have thought to use a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Kasramvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867928/kasramvd) said, I do not understand the logic behind your code. You sure your code can run without raise `IndentationError`? As I concerned, the following part (the second row, have wrong indentation).

`for number in range(0,len(s)):
 if s[number] == char:
     n = number`

If you fixed that indentation error, you can run you code without error, and the last row (`print longest`) does work, it just does not work as you expect, it only prints a blank line.

Comment: Sorry it indentation just didn't come out correctly on the website. However it is indented correctly on the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
result = ""
s = 'abchae'
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
max_length=0
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:j] in alphabet and len(s[i:j])>max_length:
            max_length = len(s[i:j])
            result = s[i:j]
print result
```

Comment: Your solutions seems really good. But I can't seem to print the end result.

Comment: I've tried print s[i:j] after the if loop, below the max_length. However, that prints after every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood what you meant.

First you need to fix the indentation problem in your code, that would make it run:

`for number in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[number] == char:
            n = number`

Second, that condition will return two numbers `0` and `4` since `a` appears two times in `s`. I believe you only want the first so you should probably add a `break` statement after you find a match.

`for number in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[number] == char:
            n = number
            break`

Finally, `alphstring in alphabet == True` will always return `False`. Because `alphabet` will never be `True`, you need parentheses to make this work or remove the `== True`.

ex: `while (alphstring in alphabet) == True and n+nxtchar <= 5:`

I believe that you were looking for the string `abch` which is what I managed to obtain with these changes